# Locate add filters element within search box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

trying to locate add filters element within the search box. Please see screenshots. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Here is the HTML for it:

```
<h3 class="display">Add Filters <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h3>
```

Comment: Here is the HTML for it: <h3 class="display">Add Filters <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></h3>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below `xpath`  :-

```
.//h3[normalize-space(.) = 'Add Filters ']/i
```

Or

```
.//h3[contains(text(),'Add Filters ')]/i
```

Or try using `cssSelector` :-

```
h3.display > .fa.fa-plus-circle
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also i have a checkbox that i like to select : <li><input type="checkbox">Standards</li>, how can i select it?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also how do i click on the information type dropdown to expand it, here is the html: <div class="expand">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i><h3>Information Type</h3>
        </div>. Once i expand it, there is a checkbox i like to select: <li><input type="checkbox">Standards</li>. Thanks